# ReactJS : TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am having trouble with a little React Router exercise

I have a File "ItemDetail.js" in which i define a Componenet "ItemDetail" which is called by a Route from another Component like so: `<Route path="/shop/:id"  component={ItemDetail}/>`.
This is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function ItemDetail({ match }) {

    const [item, setItem] = useState({});
    console.log(match);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItem();
    }, []);

    
    const fetchItem = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(`https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id=${match.params.id}`);
        const item = await data.json();
        setItem(item);
        console.log(item);
    }


    return (
      <div>
          <h3>Item: {item.data.item.name}</h3>
      </div>
  );
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

The id of the path is an id that i need for the API call (over *match.params.id*).

The fetchItem() method fetches the data I need as a JSON, I then save it in the state *item* and then render my render stuff. But it throws an error with : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined" in the line where i access `item.data.name` from JSX.

Weird thing is: when I change `<h3>Item: {item.data.item.name} </h3>` to `<h3>Item: </h3>` and then back to `<h3>Item: {item.data.item.name} </h3>` It works, just this one time, and when i refresh or navigate through my site to this path again it throws this error again

Comment: On your initial render, `item` is only set to `{}`, which means trying to access `item.data.item` will blow up (you'd be trying to access `item` on `undefined`). One common pattern to avoid this is to have something display while it's loading from the `fetch` call: `<h3>Item: {item.data ? item.data.item.name : "Loading..."}</h3>`

Comment: Ohh so it's because the code in return is is done executing before fetchItem()? Thanks that worked for me

Comment: Yeah, the `fetch` happens asynchronously, so there's definitely a render that happens before the fetch returns and you set state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need control it because react renders before you get item. You can edit like this :
So it will check when you got item it will render the page.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function ItemDetail({ match }) {

    const [item, setItem] = useState({});
    console.log(match);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchItem();
    }, []);

    
    const fetchItem = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(`https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id=${match.params.id}`);
        const item = await data.json();
        setItem(item);
        console.log(item);
    }


    return (
      <div>
         <h3>Item: {item && item.data && item.data.item ? item.data.item.name : "Loading..."}</h3>
      </div>
  );
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

Also you can use optional chaining for the short solution :
`<h3>Item: {item?.data?.item ? item.data.item.name : "Loading..."}</h3`>

Comment: Yes i forgot it, you are right. I'm editing the code.

Comment: Also i added item and item.data and item.data.item checks so it will be best check isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. Actually another much simpler option, if optional chaining is available, would be to just do something like this: `item?.data?.item?.name || "Loading..."`

Comment: I know that maybe it's not available so i added far way of solution. But it's possible.